# Is $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable on $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})$ for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=0$ for $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Is $f$ differentiable on $(0,0)$?

So let's first evaluate the partial derivatives:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}) + (x^2+y^2)\cos(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})\frac{-2x}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = 2x\left( \sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}) - \frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})}{x^2+y^2}  \right)$

By symmetry;

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2y\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}) + (x^2+y^2)\cos(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})\frac{-2x}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = 2y\left( \sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}) - \frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})}{x^2+y^2}  \right)$

Comment: Presumably, you mean with $f(0,0)=0$?

Comment: Why do you think, then, that the partials at the origin should be given by the expressions you typed? Use the definition.

Comment: OK, so first you are suggesting me to evaluate the limit $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ and conclude that $f(0,0)=0$.

Comment: @AlonAlon I don't think that's Thomas' point. His point, I believe, is that if you don't define $f$ at the origin, the problem doesn't even make sense. And unless $f(0,0)=0$, $f$ won't be continuous, much differentiable.

Comment: Oh I get you. Yes, let me edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By continuity $f(0,0)=0$ (because $0$ is the limit of $f(x,y)$ when $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ Now let us look at $$lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ This limit is also $0$ and therefore $f$ is differentiable at the origin

Comment: What? Why? I don't think this is true.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski, Why do you think so?

Comment: @AlonAlon I am sorry, i got myself confused xD , you are right!